# How do I access the JBoss data directory from inside an application?

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

I would like to upload files to my the server/default/data directory using a simple upload servlet and be able to access them from within my application, but I can't seem to find how to access it. I tried

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("data");
```

but that didn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to get the absolute path, just do:

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir");
```